# npm install returns 304 and 404 errors instead of installing packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I run `npm install` I see a lot of this:

```
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/is-arrayish 60ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/spdx-license-ids 67ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/spdx-exceptions 72ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/arr-union 11ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer 68ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/is-data-descriptor 85ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/is-accessor-descriptor 90ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/is-accessor-descriptor 72ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/is-data-descriptor 66ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/has-value 6ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/p-try 92ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/set-value 12ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/posix-character-classes 68ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/static-extend 88ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/for-in 89ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/get-value 72ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/collection-visit 88ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/to-object-path 64ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/union-value 85ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/os-homedir 81ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/unset-value 87ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/delegates 76ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/aproba 82ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/map-visit 8ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/has-unicode 76ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/wide-align 73ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/capture-stack-trace 69ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/prepend-http 83ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/has-values 81ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/object-copy 61ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/object-visit 53ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/code-point-at 52ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/pseudomap 84ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/has-values 53ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/copy-descriptor 42ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/number-is-nan 76ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/@apollographql%2fapollo-tools 726ms
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 6589ms
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @apollographql/apollo-tools@^0.4.0
npm timing npm Completed in 6995ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/paulcarron/.npm/_logs/2019-10-01T19_18_38_895Z-debug.log
```

I'm not sure why my packages won't install. I have a vague recollection of me updating the npm url some time back but the url here looks OK. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to the bottom of it. I had deleted the contents of my application folder and copied a fresh set of the program files into it. What I hadn't noticed was when I did the delete my terminal followed the path of my deleted files so was essentially pointing to a location in the trash can which seems to have caused issues with `npm install`.

Changing to the correct directory and running `npm install` again resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This command helped me:

```
npm cache clean --force
```